# Preview layout with merge root tag in Intellij IDEA/Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-tools-namespace

Let's imagine we are developing compound component based on LinearLayout. So, we create class like this:

```
public class SomeView extends LinearLayout {
    public SomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.somelayout, this);
    }
}
```

If we'll use `LinearLayout` as a root of `somelayout.xml`, we'll have extra view level, so we use merge tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some other text"/>
</merge>
```

But in Preview tab in IDE merge always acts as FrameLayout, and we'll see something like that:
[image: Preview with merge]

(It is Android Studio, Intellij IDEA is just the same, about Eclipse I don't know)

Preview speed up developing layouts a lot, it's sad lose such a great help even for some layouts. May be there is a way to specify, how Preview should interpret `merge` tag in particular layout?

Comment: I'd like to see this support added as well.

Comment: This might be solvable some time in the future by the tools attribute. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61652

Answer (score 417, accepted):

There is a new parentTag tools attribute ([added in Android Studio 2.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61652#hc29)) that you can use to specify the layout type for a merge tag, which will make the layout render correctly in the layout editor preview.

So using your example:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:parentTag="LinearLayout"
    tools:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some other text"/>
</merge>
```

**Note**: Both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` must be specified in order for the layout to display properly in the editor.

Comment: Does anyone know how to show the preview correctly when you add your custom view tag in another layout file? `<com.yourpackage.yourcustomview id="@+id/my_cust_view"  android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Comment: See visual difference https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nisrulz/android-tips-tricks/develop/img/mergetaginlayout.jpg

Comment: Since you are using tools you could as well use tools:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: The width and height tags seem to not (longer) be necessary, tested with Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 67):

Edit: Outdated answer. See answer by starkej2.

---

Android Studio 0.5.8 added support for tools:showIn. By using it it is possible to preview < merge > layouts.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio058released

layout/layout_merge.xml with tools:showIn:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:showIn="@layout/simple_relativelayout">

......

</merge>
```

layout/simple_relativelayout.xml with include:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_merge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good news! Not very handy for compound components, because we need to add extra layout only for preview. But better than nothing.

Comment: Any ideas on something similar is supported in Eclipse?

Comment: You can follow a ticket, reported by a google developer here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61652

Comment: I set some attributes to the root view (in this case RelativeLayout) programmatically, like padding. Of course they're not applied in this helper layout (because you use a completely other view). The only solution was to use the whole custom view in the helper layout.

Comment: not outdated it could be used when you don't want generic viewing

Answer (score -6):

Is also possible use custom class as parent instead of merge like

```
<com.mycompany.SomeView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
</com.mycompany.SomeView>
```

And then directly inflate this layout and cast result view to `SomeView`.
Android studio will directly check parent class of `SomeView` and handle preview like `LinerLayout`.
You can use **`onFinishInflate()`** method in the `SomeView` to bind views by `findViewById()`.
Benefit of this solution is that you can put all layout definitions or style definition directly to the layout file, you can't use method like `setOrientation()` in code.

Comment: This introduces an infinite recursion and the stack overflows when trying to preview, making the whole Android Studio hang forever.