# android preview not work for layout file using merge with tools:parentTag

Tags: android, android-layout

Acoording to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296552/preview-layout-with-merge-root-tag-in-intellij-idea-android-studio)，android xml layouts file can use tools：parentTag to preview layouts **using  tag**。
I tried tools：parentTag and the preview got empty。
If I **delete** tools：parentTag，the preview can work，so I am sure it is tools：parentTag that makes Preview not work。

this is my layout code：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:orientation="vertical"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello" />
</merge>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noMqD.png)

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preview layout with merge root tag in Intellij IDEA/Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296552/preview-layout-with-merge-root-tag-in-intellij-idea-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for `merge` tag

Comment: thanks, it works! but why I get no code suggestion when I type "android:l". Is it a bug?